# Authorization using ASP.NET Web Service

Tags: asp.net, service, web

I want to build mobile application which will be client for site. To get information from that site I need Authorization. Is it possible to make web service that job?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understood everything as your questions could provide a little bit more details.

But yes, you can build a webservice to provide both authentication and authorization using a webservice in .NET for a mobile application in whatever language you wanna do.

However, you have to be careful when designing the strategy for the subsequent calls from the application regarding the way you are going to authorize each method call. You could use WS* auth methods which are not the best IMO or perhaps a token based authentication in a more REST webservice style.